# Hashset vs Treeset

Tags: java, trees, hashing

I've always loved trees, that nice O(n*log(n)) and the tidiness of them. However, every software engineer I've ever known has asked me pointedly why I would use a TreeSet. From a CS background, I don't think it matters all that much which you use, and I don't care to mess around with hash functions and buckets (in the case of Java).

In which cases should I use a HashSet over a TreeSet?

Comment: Trees have a notion of *order of elements.*  Hash tables do not.  See also [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/advantages-of-bst-over-hash-table/) and [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/270/1353).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> From a CS background, I don't think it matters all that much which you use,

There are at least four significiant differences from a CS background:

- A hash table lookup is O(1) rather than O(log(n))
- A hash table requires a hash function, a tree requires a comparison function.
- A tree provides sorted iteration, a hash table doesn't even *have* a well defined iteration order.
- The peformance of a tree lookup degenerates to O(n) when it's imbalanced, but implementations can avoid this completely by being auto-rebalancing. Hash table lookup performance degenerates to O(n) when there are too many collisions, and avoiding this completely is very hard (Java's implementation manages this since Java 8, but only if the keys are also comparable - it switches to using a tree internally).

> and I don't care to mess around with hash functions and buckets (in the case of Java).

You don't have to worry about buckets *at all*, the implementation class hides that from you completely. You do need a decent `hashCode()` implementation (an an `equals()` consistent with it), but that is not hard to come by.

> In which cases should I use a HashSet over a TreeSet?

When you cannot easily define a comparison function, or when performance is essential - O(1), remember? There is also an implementation quirk: `HashMap` allows you to use `null` as a key value, `TreeMap` does not.

But nowadays the recommendation really is to always use a HashSet (for the superior performance) unless you have specific reasons not to (typically when you need the sorted iteration).

Comment: Hash tables also have a mode where they degrade into `O(absurd)`.  Trees, of course, will do that also if you don't keep them balanced.

Comment: @RobertHarvey only with poor implementations, or if someone knows your hashing function and how to attack it.

Comment: For "In which cases should I use a HashSet over a TreeSet?" the practical guideline I'd use based on the things you pointed out (and that was used whereever I worked): Always use HashSet unless you really really need to maintain that ordering. It's much more likely you run into performance issues with a TreeSet than into any other problems with a HashSet . Feel free to incorporate that if you agree into your answer (or not if you don't obviously^^)

Comment: @RobertHarvey: That's more of a theoretical view, since the tree implementation in Java is of course balanced, and the HashMap actually only degenerates to tree behaviour since Java 8 (if the keys are also comparable): https://www.nagarro.com/en/blog/post/24/performance-improvement-for-hashmap-in-java-8

Comment: @FrankHopkins: right, I added a remark at the end.